# How can I check if I have 2 different os versions installed on my mac

Tags: macos

I recently downgraded from Catalina to Mojave. During this process I realised that internally I had 2 drives (Did not make sense). One labelled Macintosh HD and the other Macintosh HD - Data. The data one turned out to be my startup drive for Catalina and I wiped it and reinstalled Mojave. However, I had noticed that the other drive was taking up around 10 GB. As such, I am confused as to whether Catalina exists on that other drive or what is taking up that space as I would like to free it up.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: maybe this would help? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255

Comment: I guess these questions should be asked on [this stackexchange site](http://apple.stackexchange.com/). Also, the most reliable solution is call the apple customer care (000 800 1009 009). They are really helpful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ask on the apple.SE site, enjoy!

Comment: Basically use "DiskUtility" to "get rid of" the pointless partitions.

Comment: the apple. site is great, enjoy!